# How to avoid codeigniter skipping empty URL parameters

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am using Codeigniter with the following URL (as a sample)

```
domain.com/index.php/controller/method/p1/p2/p3
```

The problem is one of functions sometimes doesn't return p2. This has resulted in the following url

```
domain.com/index.php/controller/method/p1//p3
```

In my controller, I have the method set as follows:

```
public function (p1 = FALSE, p2 = FALSE, p3 = FALSE) {code}
```

However, when p2 is empty as above, suddenly p2 doesn't return false but instead returns p3 and p3 doesn't return anything. Why is this and how to avoid? (I have searched extensively but can't seem to work out what the issue is)

Comment: There really isn't anything you can do. Browsers assume the double slash is just one hence p3 takes the place of p2.

Comment: The only thing you could possibly do is to have them start with different identifiers so you can identify if p3 is in p2's place.

Comment: wherever you build your url, you could detect if p2 doesn't return nothing and then set it to 0; So your url would look like `domain.com/index.php/controller/method/p1/0/p3`

Answer (score 0):

to prevent missing parameter issues you should use the following code

make your routes like below

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'controller/method';
```

`.*` => it will return all parametar after the method

update your function as below

```
public function () {
    $controller = $this->uri->segment(1); // controller
    $method = $this->uri->segment(2); // method
    $param1 = $this->uri->segment(3); // p1
    $param2 = $this->uri->segment(4); // p2
    $param3 = $this->uri->segment(5); // p3
}
```